# Are there any browsers that do not have Arial available?

Tags: css, fonts

I recently updated my body tag CSS from

```
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
```

to

```
  font-family: Arial;
```

b.c. I assume that all modern browsers support Arial.

Is this O.K. ?

My understanding is that Helvetica & san-serif are only fallback fonts if Arial does not exist.

Answer (score 7):

Font support is related to the user system, not browser. Arial is a pretty-standard font, available in all major Operational Systems. 
Also, "sans-serif" is not a fallback font as you stated, but the typographic style of the font you intended to use.
Looking at your code:

> font-family: Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;

It means: try use Arial first. If not available, Helvetica. If none of them is possible, then use any the default sans-serif font designated by the system.

For your specific case for extra security try using "Arial, sans serif" because in a worst-case scenario the browser will not mess your layout with a Serif font, which is the default font-family style applied.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by security ... but I just don't think there will ever be a case were `Arial` does not exist.

Comment: actually me neither, but you never know with so many mobile and in-app browsers nowadays...